# why some character like # in routes.MapPageRoute and LINQ don't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, special-characters

I have problem with some **characters** like  **#** in **routes.MapPageRoute** and LINQ.
how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is not sent by the browser. It's a client side only feature, for defining anchors in the document.

You can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is sent.